# ACM Jolly Jumpers 2

Tags: c++

I have problem with this question I dont know what is wrong with my code any help could be greatfull here is the link of the question http://sharecode.ir/sections/problem/problemset/2175
I test it in several testcase but it work currectly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <int> num;
    vector <int> num1;
    int n,temp,j=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i= 0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        cin>>temp;
        num.push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<num.size() ; i++)
    {
        if(i+1 < num.size())
        {
            num1.push_back(abs(num[i]-num[i+1]));
        }
    }
    for(int i=0 ; i<num1.size() ; i++)
    {
        if(i+1 < num1.size())
        {
            if(num1[i] == num1[i+1])
            {
                cout<<"Not jolly"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    sort(num1.begin(),num1.end());
    for(int i=0 ; i<num1.size() ; i++)
    {
        if(i+1 < num1.size())
        {
            if(num1[i]+1 != num1[i+1])
            {
                cout<<"Not jolly"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Jolly"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you getting?

Comment: when I send it in I get wrong answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work for a sequence which has increasing distance between members, but the smallest distance is not 1. Consider this input:

```
3 5 10 11
```

The differences are 5 and 6. The first test does not fire, because they are indeed different. The second test also does not fire, because `6 == 5 + 1`. But it's still not a jolly jumper.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem you have, is you should read the input till `EOF`.

As the input specification says:

> Each line of input contains an integer n < 3000 followed by n integers representing the sequence.

You have put a while around your algorithm and process numbers coming from input.
You current code will process just the first input now.